# Dividing a 1D-encoded 2D array into sectors

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have a image encoded into a 1D array of colors (represented with letters here for simplicity):

```
[A, B, C, D,
 E, F, G, H,
 I, J, K, L,
 M, N, O, P]
```

But because of limitations of a library I use, every image must be under `maxElements` items, and square. So what I need to do is extract "sectors" from that image, so I can iterate them separately. Example for `maxElements  = 4`:

```
[A, B, [C, D,
 E, F]  G, H]
[I, J, [K, L,
 M, N]  O, P]
```

If there is a remainder, it should be stored on a smaller array. Example for `side = 3`, `maxElements = 4`:

```
[A, B, C,      [[A, B, [C,
 D, E, F,  ->    D, E]  F]
 G, H, I]       [G, H] [I]]
```

Note that the array was cut at column 3, since if its dimensions were to go over 2x2, it would violate `maxElements`.

However, an added challenge is that I don't have access to this image until too late, but I do have the image's *side* (as in square side) and the max element count per sector. So what I want to do is generate an array of indices to each pixel in the array.

So I have the length of each row in the 1D array and the number of rows (both being the *side*), and I need to generate a array of indices to that to-be-obtained array. Example output for `side = 4`, `maxElements = 4`:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 7, 8], [9, 10, 13, 14], [11, 12, 15, 16]]
```

Maybe I'm just too much time without sleep, but I can't knock off a solution to this.

Comment: `[i, i + 1, i + side, i + 1 + side]` `for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i += side / 2)`

Comment: Why in the last example, we cannot divide the last array into `[C,F,I]`? as the side is 3 and maxElements is 4, so this should be valid?

Comment: @PhamTrung That woud be even better, but I imagine it might be more complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After returning to this problem, I've found a solution:

```
public static List<List<int>> SectorizeMap<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, int width, int maxPerSector) {
    var sectorSide = (int)Math.Sqrt(maxPerSector);
    var widthSectors = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)width / sectorSide);
    var resultSectors = new List<List<int>>();

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Count(); i++) {
        var x = i % width;
        var y = i / width;
        var sectorX = x / sectorSide;
        var sectorY = y / sectorSide;
        var sectorIndex = sectorY * widthSectors + sectorX;
        if (resultSectors.Count <= sectorIndex) {
            resultSectors.Add (new List<int> ());
        }
        resultSectors[sectorIndex].Add(i);
    }
    return resultSectors;
}
```

With the following example:

```
var resultSectors = SectorizeMap(Enumerable.Range(0, 36), 6, 4);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", 
    resultSectors.Select(sec => string.Format("[{0}]", 
        string.Join(", ", sec)))));
```

## How it works

We start receiving the input array, its width (when represented in 2D) and the maximum amount of items per sector.

1. Since sectors are square, take the root of the maximum amount of items per sector and use it as the dimension for both sides of a sector.
2. Calculate how many sectors fit on a row.
3. Iterate the input:

   1. Decode the element's index to a (x, y) pair.
   2. Assign a sector-wise (x, y) pair to these coordinates
   3. Convert the sector-wise coordinates into a index
   4. Add the current element's index to the sector at our calculated position, creating it if necessary.
4. Return the list of sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough idea:

To access the `(x,y)`th element in an 1D representation of a 2D array: `x + y*H`.
Suppose we want to access x = 1 and y = 2 in your array (W=4, H=4):
`arr[1 + 2*4] == arr[9] = J`.

Since we know how to access an element by coordinates, we can use a loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < W; x += 2) {
  for (int y = 0; y < H; y += 2)
    output[(x/2) + (y/2)*(H/2)] = new int[] { arr[x + y*H],     arr[(x+1) + y*H], 
                                          arr[x + (y+1)*H], arr[(x+1) + (y+1)*H] };
  }
}
```

This is the rough sketch. To handle the `side = 3 maxElements = 4` case, you need bounds checking, to check if `(x+1)<W` and `(y+1)<H`. That means, there are four cases:

```
bool xi = (x+1)<W, yi = (y+1)<H;
if (xi && yi) // both within range
  output[...] = new int[] { arr[...], arr[...], arr[...], arr[...] };
if (!xi && yi) // only y within range
  output[...] = new int[] { arr[...], arr[...] };
if (xi && !yi) // only x within range
  output[...] = new int[] { arr[...], arr[...] };
else // both out of range
  output[...] = new int[] { arr[...] };
```